# java.util.NoSuchElementException even though hasMOreTokens included

Tags: java, string, token

I am using map and reduce to print pair of words divided by spaces and removing their punctuation symbols like this. It worked for a moment and now gives me the error of no elementEsception. Am I doing something wrong?

```
String line = value.toString();
String delim = " ";
boolean returnDelims = false;
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, delim, returnDelims );//separa el string line en   tokens         
String prevToken = tokenizer.nextToken();
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String currToken = tokenizer.nextToken();
    String CurrentPrint = prevToken + " " + currToken.replace(",", "").replace(".", "");
    if(!prevToken.contains(",")&&!prevToken.contains("."))
```

...//print CurrentPrint
    }

The error is on the first line that uses hasMoreTokens: Sorry I cannot copy in in cloudera terminal. But yes it worked one time.
[image]

Comment: can you show us the full error please

Comment: Edited the question  @YCF_L

Comment: Can you add you full loop? I think you are doing two times nextToken inside the loop

Comment: @Gatusko No once the loop finishes there with printing the cURRENTpRINT

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if your 'line' is empty String (line="").

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a check before retrieving the first token, as well.

```
String line = value.toString();
String delim = " ";
boolean returnDelims = false;
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, delim, returnDelims );//separa el string line en   tokens    
if(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){     
    String prevToken = tokenizer.nextToken();
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String currToken = tokenizer.nextToken();
        String CurrentPrint = prevToken + " " + currToken.replace(",", "").replace(".", "");
        //... handle tokens
    }
}else{
    // handle empty line
}
```